# Weird Behavior in Windows XP with Python snippet

Tags: python-2.7, windows-xp

I wrote a snippet that would automatically copy a file from a source directory to a path on an usb. Because drive letter names are assigned by the PC independent o the slot I figured I would GetLogicalDrives() and if the path to the usb directory is in any of those drives then it would copy (I hope I'm making some sense). Here is the piece of code I wrote in Python:

```
import itertools, ctypes, string, sys, os.path, shutil

def drive_list():
    drive_bitmask = ctypes.cdll.kernel32.GetLogicalDrives()
    drive_list = list(itertools.compress(string.ascii_uppercase,
               map(lambda x:ord(x) - ord('0'), bin(drive_bitmask)[:1:-1])))
    return drive_list

for drive in drive_list():
    path = drive + ":\\targer_directory\target_file.ext"
    if drive not in ["C", "D", "E"]:
        if os.path.exists(path) == True:
            shutil.copy2(r'C:\source_directory\source_file.ext', path)
```

Whenever I run this script I get a bunch of error messages saying:

"Exception Processing Message c0000013 Parameters 75b1bf7c 4 75b1bf7c 75b1bf7c"

I think this probably means that I have some "ghost drives" in my pc. Any help in bypassing this behavior is deeply appreciated.

Note: The code runs at the end and the copy job is done succesfuly, but not until the error messages are cleared which is not the objective if I want to perform automatic backups.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure whether this will help or not. But you can try this!

We were receiving the same error on execution of a windows application (an .exe file) and the below steps resolved it.

Goto **Registry Editor**
(Run -> type 'regedit' -> hit enter)

- Expand **HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE**
- Expand **System**
- Expand **CurrentControlSet**
- Expand **Control**
- Select **Windows**
- Double click on **ErrorMode** in the right side pane
- Set the **Value Data** as **2**
- Click **OK**
- Restart your system